# How to make my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS auto upgrade to latest Linux Kernel?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I just want my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version to have a latest Linux Kernel everytime it gets new release like ArchLinux has. I looked for the answers in google but had really hard time figuring out so I thought I'd ask here and get a quick easy answer. I'm not looking forward to use Ubuntu 19.04 or any latest version instead would love to have Linux 5.0.** on my Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: If you have the [LTS Enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) installed you should be getting 5.0 installed in August 2019 with 18.04.3.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support

Answer (score 1):

That's not how Ubuntu is set up; Ubuntu does not follow the strategy Arch uses.

The idea is to upgrade your system to 19.04 is you want newer versions of software/a kernel. If you want a newer kernel in 18.04 you will need to update your system yourself. 18.04 will get the 19.04 kernel somewhere later this year when the next point release arrives (18.04.02).

---

There is a tool called Ubuntu kernel update (UKUU) that makes this rather easy though:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ukuu
```

After starting ukuu you will get a list of available kernels and you can add the one you want to the system. As the old ones are still there you can then always pick an older one from grub if the newest is not to your liking.

Issue with this... it is not free...

> [Purchase](https://teejeetech.in/ukuu/)
>
> A personal license for Ukuu is currently available for $12. This is a single-user license that is valid for lifetime, and includes future updates.

**Note: Do not upgrade your kernel if you do not know what you are doing.**

Comment: +1; I agree with the final comment 'Do not upgrade your kernel if you do not know what you are doing'. I would like to add that it is straightforward and rather safe to upgrade within the same kernel series (for example within  the 4.15 series for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`). But it is more complicated and risky to upgrade to another kernel series; this is what I would warn about.

Comment: ukuu has moved to a paid model structure, and may not be available for free, or in anything possibly except old versions of ukuu on older versions of Ubuntu. See https://teejeetech.in/ukuu/ and https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu

Comment: I missed that @heynnema pity :P